# SSRS Multiple Criteria In Countrows IF Expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I'm having trouble putting 2 criteria into a countrows expression in report builder 3.0, I'm sure its something very simple or impossible but I just can't do it! I only want to bring back values which meet the 2 criteria below in one single expression.

=Sum(IIF(Fields!COL1.Value = "X", 1, 0))
AND
=Sum(IIF(Fields!COL2.Value = "Y", 1, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine them as one `IIF` :

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!COL1.Value = "X" and Fields!COL2.Value = "Y", 1, 0))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have put countrows instead of SUM, it doesn't work when I put countrows and brings back 0 when I use SUM which I know isn't the answer.

Comment: The logic of this sum is correct! I don't know a lot about ssrs syntax, so maybe something else is wrong here, but this is suppose to do the same as countrows. Maybe a single quote mark `'` for string comparison instead of two? `"`

Comment: Ah, it was an 'or' instead of an 'and' otherwise it just cancels itself out.